# "Something bad has happened" trying to list my Famous Questions

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just tried clicking on the "famous question" badge bar to list my famous questions (on superuser.com, not the meta). I got this:

https://superuser.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/help/badges/28/famous-question

this was from my main profile page; then I tried it from the "badges" page - same result.

FYI.

Comment: Is this persistent or was it a one-time thing?

Comment: @rahuldottech: Hasn't happened before. It was persistent for a couple of minutes or so, but now it seems ok.

Comment: eh, happens sometimes, nothing to really worry about, IMO

Comment: @rahuldottech: Just doing my civic duty. Also, when I reported this it was still persisting...

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/FPGD2Wt.png

Comment: there's some redis related stuff going on. Its PROBABLY transient, but shog knows. Well actually Nick knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We removed some help posts around Documentation, which had references in memory (ah, ha! another name for cache, which is always the issue!) that weren't properly purged.

The cache was flushed and the error should now be fixed!